# html_entity_decode for POST/GET value

Tags: php, html-encode

I have a text like this:

```
加入营销计划 Informática \xf3
```

and i want to do html_entity_decode

If I'm saying

```
$str = $_GET['str']
```

... where `$_GET['str']` is my string

```
html_entity_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

... will return the same string, with no change.

But, if I'm saying

```
$str = "加入营销计划 Informática \xf3";
html_entity_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

... will return modified string. Why and what I should do to have the correct value when I get the string from GET/POST ?

Comment: It'd be interesting to see your *raw* URL string.

Comment: `加入营销计划 Informática \xf3` doesn't have any HTML entities in it. What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0):

I feel that's because $_GET doesn't accept `\` in your $_GET string. try to `base64_encode();` your string and put it  to $_GET['str'] (it means that you will have another link without these chars)